# columns Excel source configured to unicode in SSIS, but some of them are read as float

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

For last few days I am troubling with an SSIS package to configure an Excel source that contain different types of data. And I have configured it to unicode (DT_WSTR) for all columns, but while loading some them are implicitly converted to float. I could see them in the data viewer. This happens for some numeric fields. And the data in the numeric column looks like below.

```
1
0.5
1
0.5
```

I tried all the ways in my knowledge. adding `IMEX=1` and `TypeGuessRows=0` and `ValidateExternalMetadata= False` etc.

Comment: Post examples of the source data, SSIS mappings, and results.

Comment: what is your destination, you do not need to configure all as DT_WSTR, unless for an error in conversion from destination

Comment: @Bovas it is good to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about asking question and accepting answers. also after reading the whole page you will earn the "informed" badge wich let the other users know that you are an informed users. so they will help you more

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `IMEX=1` to the connection string, and you can try adding a dummy row which contains string values after the column header, as example:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
aaa        aaa        aaa
1          1          0.5
2          0.5        1
```

Or just select that the first row doesn't contains column header, and skip the first rows in the import process (it can be done by adding `HDR=NO` to the connection string)